# Inheritance in python (Flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am a little bit confused regarding inheritance features in python 3.8.0. I am actually working on JAVA platform for a long time. Recently I am working on the Python (version 3.8.0) platform. Bellow, I share the folder structure of my flask project:

```
- ProjectFolder
  - src 
    - configs
      - appconfig.py
    - controllers
      - controller1.py
    - models
      - model1.py
    - routeservices
      - routs.py
    - templates
      page1.html
 - app.py
```

Above file structure is my project file structure. 
in "app.py" :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from routeservices import routs   #This line not work properly
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My question is what is the best way to resolve the inheritance issue in python (Flask)

Comment: How did `inheritance` come into picture. You know there is an inheritance in `OOP`, right?

Comment: inheritance is when a class inherits from another, it's not about folder structure

Comment: Read https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/index.html many times, it's very helpful, I may have read it 10 times, to get all. This topic https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/organizing.html is about your question

Comment: This is not a flask related problem, neither inheritance, the problem is that for python to recognize your folder `routeservices` as a module, you need to put an empty file `__init__.py` inside it than it should work, otherwise python won't recognize `routservices` as a module

Comment: Some clarification:
in java we define those folder structures as packages right. if we want to import any java file then we write the import statement then we make a object some thing like that . In python I am confused how I same technique?

Comment: You aren't asking about inheritance, you're asking how Python packages work. Start here: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/